# Using a dictionary file with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a blacklist.txt file that contains keywords I want to remove using sed.

Here's what the blacklist.txt file contain

```
winston@linux ] $ cat blacklist.txt   
obscure
keywords
here
...
```

And here's what I have so far, but currently doesn't work.

```
  blacklist=$(cat blacklist.txt);
  output="filtered_file.txt"

  for i in $blacklist;
    do
      cat $input | sed 's/$i//g' >> $output
    done
```

Comment: this is inefficient. If you have 1000 blacklist words, you will process your input file 1000 times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to remove lines that contains words in that blacklist

```
grep -v -f blacklist.txt inputfile > filtered_file.txt
```

if you want to remove just the words alone

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
 blacklist[$0]
 next
}
{
 for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
   if ($i in blacklist){
     $i=""
   }
 }
}1' blacklist inputfile > filtered_file.txt
```

Comment: you are removing the whole line

Comment: only with the `grep` solution.

Comment: +1 for the `awk` solution removing whole words as opposed to substrings too (and properly handling special e.g. regexp characters in the blacklisted words.) You should probably fix or remove the "just the shell" solution.

Comment: yes you are right. the shell solution is a different. i could probably "cut" the line up , but i'll just stick to awk.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `sed` twice:  once on the blacklist to create a sed program that eliminates every line in blacklist, and then a second time applying that generated sed script to your real data.

First,

```
$ sed -e 's@^@s/@' -e 's@$@//g' < blacklist.txt > script.sed
```

If `blacklist.txt` looks like

```
word1
word2
....
wordN
```

then `script.sed` will look like

```
s/word1//g
s/word2//g
...
s/word3//g
```

You might find the use of `@` characters above a bit confusing. The normal way of writing a `sed` substitute command is `s/old/new/`.  This is quite awkward if either of *old* or *new* contain a forward slash.  So, `sed` allows you to to use any character you want immediately after the substitute command.  This means that you can write `s@foo/bar@plugh/plover@` instead of `s/foo\/bar/plugh\/plover/`.  I think you'll agree that the former is **much** easier to read.

Once you have `script.sed` generated, run

```
$ sed -f script.sed < file > censored-file
```

You can of course use the new-fangled (ie, less than 20 years old) `-i` option to do in-place editing.

Comment: and he can, of course, do it all inline without an intermediate .sed file: `sed -e "\`sed -e 's@^@s/@;s@\$@//g' <blacklist.txt | tr -s '[\n]' ';'\`" <file >censored-file`

Comment: An alternative inline way is `sed 's|.*|s/\<&\>//g|' blacklist.txt | sed -f - file >censored-file`